# Is this a Markov Chain and/or Poisson thing?

Tags: machine-learning, python, poisson-distribution, markov-process, poisson-regression

I know how to predict the winner of a football match in Python with a simple / multiple regression model, or Bayes. But I have the intuition that the last matches played are more relevant for the outcome than the older ones.

How can I give more weight to the last matches than the older ones in my statistical model?

Comment: ok i will do right now, I understand the rules of stack. will make shorter the question, and ask only one

Comment: As a first hint, this looks similar to a common problem in reinforcement learning, with the "reward discount" gamma factor as the most usual solution, and "reward shaping" as the latest trend. There is also [the exponentially weighted moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponentially_weighted_moving_variance_and_standard_deviation) in a similar vein. In any case, I don't think a Markov Chain is what you are looking for, except if you want to totally discard previous observations except the last, but it looks to me that you rather want to weight proportionally to time.

Comment: thank you @gaborous, I am going to accept your reply if there are not other ones more exhaustive, if you could put a graph/image, it will possibly appear as a reply, so that I can accept you and upvote you. Now I have definitely a starting point to orient my self if I want to make a python model, regarding the reinforcement learning I knew so far only UCB and Thompson sampling.

Comment: I can't post a reply until the question is put "off hold" :-) But I'm pretty sure someone will give a more detailed and useful answer than mine!

Comment: Although there is no question this is broad, it should be answerable. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Thanks @gung, After read your reply I further re-edit the post to  try make it shorter, clearer and more focused.

Comment: After the edit, I can't even find an intelligible question.  I'm sorry about having to close the thread again.  cc @gung

Comment: Yeah, it was broad, but clearer, before, @whuber.

Comment: @gaborous was right, I was looking for an exponentially weighted moving average, thank you.  Now that I looked into the documentation, it looks even trivial. Anyway I am  really happy I learned something.

Comment: I rewrote the question, hopefully this should be OK now. Glad you already have the answer trocchietto :-) But I'm pretty sure there are other ways to discount/weight relatively to time, it would certainly be interesting to have other answers.

Comment: make sense, but as a relative beginner,  was great to have some basic fundamentals by your reply, now we can indeed build upon.